# Calling member function of an object inside a vector

Tags: c++, object, vector, private, members

*This is a continuation on my previous question here regarding [retrieving and editing private members of objects in a vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5836000/retrieving-and-editing-private-members-of-objects-in-a-vector).*

I have a vector full of objects that have private members that I need to access. **I have created accessor functions for returning each private member and am now looking for the best way to iterate through the vector of objects, returning a specific private member from it and comparing it to a given variable until a match is found.**

I have considered using `find_if` but have had no luck with using a member functions return value, for each object in the vector, as criteria.

Neither have I been able to use `for_each` to do the job.

The reason I am creating an additional question is that I've been dwelling for this longer than I should and it's getting to become quite urgent that I find a solution to the problem. Any nudge in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Create a functor:

```
struct CompareTo{
    CompareTo(const AnotherObject& aValue) : theValue(aValue){}

    bool operator()(const Object& anObject) const{
        return anObject.getMemberVar() == theValue;
    }

    const AnotherObject& theValue;
};
```

that can be put into the `find_if`.